# Falloff object/collection instancing (Animation nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

I am trying to instance collection instances on a spline with a falloff so that I have a different collection instance from a certain point.

With regular objects everything works totally fine, but I can't get it to work using collection instances.
I want to avoid joining meshes, rearranging origins and applying modifier in the main file, because that would cause problems.

Could someone help me out?
I attached the blend file.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instance collection instances using empties.
Generate empties using `Object Instancer` and set its `instance_type` to `COLLECTION`. Then set collection instances as `instance_collection` values.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for your clear and comprehensive answer. I have to wait 7 hours before being able to release the bounty, so I will do that tomorrow. Thanks again, you are a Blender hero!